# Why text features are disabled?

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape 1.0 I found new text "Features" tab:

[image]

Even capitals are disabled, why? How to use this Features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These features depend on the fonts installed. Not all features are supported in all fonts. Those that aren't supported will be greyed out.

For example to get Small Caps to work, you need to install a font that supports it.

In the example below I have installed Alegreya in my system fonts. This is a font which is freely available on google fonts, and it supports small caps

Once installed, Small, All small, and Normal are available options for Alegreya.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for fixing `:)` I see you deleted the note about installing (the `*` is still in your text...) – I've always wondered what the difference is. Since you removed it, it does not matter how they are installed?

Comment: @usr2564301 I removed it because they fixed the "install for all users" font problem in Inkscape 1.0 on Windows 10. Removed the asterisk too;)